# How is it that I can modify a final variable in Java when calling a method recursively

Tags: java

```
public class MyClass {

    public void display(String s) {
        final char c = s.charAt(0);
        System.out.println(c);
        if (s.length() > 1) {
            display(s.substring(1));

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass mC = new MyClass();
        mC.display("SampleString");
    }

}
```

When I execute the following code how is that I am able to modify the value of final variable c when calling display recursively. Isnt final supposed to restrict the user from doing that

Comment: You aren't modifying any variables.

Comment: You are just creating a new instance of your variable when you call your display method

Comment: So, even if I am calling display recursively each time new initialization happens for the variable c?

Comment: @kapilchhattani yes your just creating new instance of it. your variable is inside of the scope of display method.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I get what is happening.

Comment: welcome :) im glad that i was able to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable c is scoped inside its enclosing method. That's why when you call it recursively, each time it is different variable c.

Answer (score 3):

You are not modifying the variable, each call of this method gets a new instance of the variable.  If you only want one instance you can move the declaration into the class body and declare it "static".

Answer (score 0):

You are not modifying a `final` variable, you are creating a new stack frame and that creates a new variable `c` for your method `display`. Also, your method takes one `char` from the `String` each time, and you get a new `String`. So,

```
 public void display(final String s) { // <-- you *could* make `s` final
    if (s == null || s.length() < 1) return;
    final char c = s.charAt(0);
    System.out.print(c); // <-- why put each char on a new line?
    if (s.length() > 1) {
        display(s.substring(1)); // <-- recurse.
    } else {
        System.out.println(); // <-- last char. new line.
    }
}
```